# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y}{2x+1}$ with initial condition of $y(0)=e$ for $x>-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I do separation by variables, I get to $\frac{1}{2}\ln|y|=\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+1|+C$ but then I'm not sure what to do from here.

I want to multiply by $2$, exponentiate, and then solve for $y$. Then I get $y=e^{2c} (2x+1)$

Comment: Sub in $x=0, y=e$ to get an equation for $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x >-1/2$ we have $|2x+1|=2x+1.$ then we get

$$\ln|y|=\ln(2x+1)+c$$

Since $y(0)=e>0$, we see that

$$\ln y=\ln(2x+1)+c,$$

hence

$$y(x)=e^c(2x+1)$$

From $y(0)=e>0$, we derive $e=e^c$, thus $c=1.$

The solution of the IVP is given by

$$y(x)=e(2x+1).$$